# feature detection в верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, теория

Хотелось бы побольше узнать об этом подходе, приминительно к верстке. Пытался что-нибудь нагуглить, но безуспешно((( Не могли бы подсказать,что можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Это проверка, которая определяет, какие возможности HTML5 и CSS3 поддерживает браузер пользователя, обычно используется библиотека Modernizr https://modernizr.com/

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css-feature-detection-modernizr-or-feature-queries--cms-23508

Comment: Можно еще почитать о [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)